# sql query returning twice the amount of data needed

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql query that looks like so:

```
    public function get_data() {

    $db = new databaseConnection();
    $db->do_connection();

    $this->uid = $_SESSION['uid'];

    $query = "SELECT ut.level, ut.location, ui.quantity, ui.game_item_id
            FROM user_table ut, user_inventory ui
            WHERE ut.user_id = ui.user_id
            AND ut.user_id = :user_id";
    $args = array(
        ":user_id" => $this->uid
    );
    $db->safeQuery($query,$args);

    $results = $db->safe_fetch_all_results();
    if($results == null){
        die ('Error with user data fetch');
    }

    var_dump($results);

    return $results;

}
```

The query works as i want, but for some reason the var_dump shows the data coming back as this:

```
array (size=2)
0 => 
array (size=8)
  'level' => string '1' (length=1)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  'location' => string '4554' (length=4)
  1 => string '4554' (length=4)
  'quantity' => string '2' (length=1)
  2 => string '2' (length=1)
  'game_item_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  3 => string '1' (length=1)
1 => 
  array (size=8)
  'level' => string '1' (length=1)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  'location' => string '4554' (length=4)
  1 => string '4554' (length=4)
  'quantity' => string '1' (length=1)
  2 => string '1' (length=1)
  'game_item_id' => string '5' (length=1)
  3 => string '5' (length=1)
```

As you can see for each record being retrieved by the query, a duplicate is also being retrieved, one with the field name and one with an index number if you wish.

I get the same result when i do a nested foreach statement, i get the duplicate results.

Here is the structure of my tables:

user_table table

```
user_ID PK
username
password
email
level
location
```

game_items table

```
game_item_is PK
item_name
```

user_inventory table

```
user_inventory_id PK
user_id FK
game_item_id FK
quantity
```

Would you guys happen to know why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's standard behaviour...
If you Fetch the data from the resultset, you can choose to retrieve it by association (FETCH_ASSOC), by index, or both (FETCH_BOTH)

Comment: Ok so instead of using fetchAll, i can use either fetch_assoc to return just one set of the resultsets?